# Merge multiple images into different combinations

Tags: image, merge

In my folder i have 4 pics every time in a 4X6 pic size.
In next step i want to show all the 4 pic's into different cobinations to user like, {pics: 1 2 3 4}

image 1: 1+2;
image2: 1+2+3;

image3: 2;

image4: 1+2+3+4;

how do i can achive this...in .net/any technology please suggest.

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? Working out the combinatins? Joining the images? Displaying the images?

Comment: When you say *all combinations*, do you mean 4 single pictures, then all the possible pairs, then all the possible triptychs, then all four pictures with each one in each different place?

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? One above the other? Side by side? Composited on top of each other? How do you merge 3 images? Side by side? In a vertical row? In a triangle? What about 4 images? Four in a row horizontally? Vertically? Two by two?

Comment: actually its for a photo booth. i am taking 4 pics at a time, after that i would like give option to user to select between the combinations created with the four images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this with **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX, and Windows. At the command-line, in Terminal, side by side:

```
convert a.png b.png +append result.png
```

[image]

Or, above and below:

```
convert a.png b.png -append result.png
```

[image]

Or, 4-up:

```
convert a.png b.png +append \( c.png d.png +append \) -append result.png
```

[image]

Or 4-across:

```
convert a.png b.png c.png d.png +append result.png
```

[image]

If your images are JPEG, just change the extensions. If you are on Windows, you may need to put carets (`^`) in front of the `\` or `(` to escape them.

Comment: Thanks you Mark...it's helped me!!

Comment: I forgot to mention there is a .Net port of ImageMagick https://magick.codeplex.com